# How to show remaining days of ".SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays())" on label? Asp.net core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, data-protection

Tools used : Visual Studio 2019, Asp.net core 5.0.

**I'm building a small app and would like to see on a label the remaining days before expiration.**

On startup.cs i have set :
.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

**How can i read the expiration date from the KeyLifetime?**

Comment: `How can i read the expiration date from the KeyLifetime?` Have you tried to get key(s) and information about CreationDate and ExpirationDate etc via [`IKeyManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.keymanagement.ikeymanager?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Besides, the data protection system will perform automatic key management, do you want to manually manage keys?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Can you give an example?

Comment: `_keyManager.GetAllKeys()` can help fetch all keys.

Comment: Where do i have to declare the _keyManager.GetAllKeys(), on the *.cshtml.cs page, on a controller, on startup...? If it is possible, can you provide a sample page so i can understand where and how to use this. I have no experience in IKeyManager implementation. The links i looked on aren't helping me understand.

Comment: To make use of `GetAllKeys` method, you can inject IKeyManager into the constructor of your controller class first, like this `public HomeController(IKeyManager keyManager) { _keyManager = keyManager; }`.

Comment: @FeiHan       public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IKeyManager _keyManager;


        public IndexModel(IKeyManager keyManager)
        {
            _keyManager = keyManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }
  

          public IKeyManager  KeyManager { get; set; }
    
    
            public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
  
  KeyManager = (IKeyManager)_keyManager.GetAllKeys();
  
  }
 }
 
 The error i get is:
 
 System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type ...

 
 What is missing on this code?